# Combine rows/columns from two tables - JOIN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, left-join

In the link see my  [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ac0d1/1) and see b

```
CREATE TABLE Projects
    (`p_id` int, `project_title` varchar(9), `l_id` int);
INSERT INTO Projects
    (`p_id`, `project_title`, `l_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 6),
    (2, 'B', 6),
    (3, 'C', 7),
    (4, 'D', 8),
    (5, 'E', 9),
    (6, 'F', 10);
CREATE TABLE Locations
    (`l_id` int, `title` varchar(9), `parent_id` int );
INSERT INTO Locations
    (`l_id`, `title`, `parent_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Country', 0),
    (2, 'District1', 1),
    (3, 'District2', 1),
    (4, 'District3', 1),
    (5, 'District4', 1),
    (6, 'Loc 5', 2),
    (7, 'Loc 6', 3),
    (8, 'Loc 7', 3),
    (9, 'Loc 8', 4),
    (10, 'Loc 9', 4),
    (11, 'Loc 10', 4),
    (12, 'Loc 11', 5);
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
+------+-----------+-------------+
| L_ID | Title     | count P_ID  | 
+------+-----------+-------------+
|  2   | District1 |    2        | 
|  3   | District2 |    2        | 
|  4   | District3 |    2        | 
|  5   | District4 |    0        | 
+----+------------+------+-------+
```

I have tried with INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN. All i can achieve is  like below and doesnt help me:

```
    +------+-----------+----------------------+
    | L_ID | Title     | parent_id  | counted |
    +------+-----------+------------+---------+
    |  6   | Loc 5     |    2       |   2     | 
    |  7   | Loc 6     |    3       |   2     | 
    |  9   | Loc 8     |    4       |   2     | 
    +---- -+-----------+------------+---------+
```

Locations table is a nested one, if this matters.  I need to count projects that are in each District and also to get District name.

I tried:

```
SELECT l.*, COUNT(p.l_id) AS thecounted 
FROM locations l 
INNER JOIN  projects p  ON p.l_id = l.l_id  
GROUP BY l.parent_id
```

and

```
SELECT l.*, COUNT(p.l_id) AS thecounted 
FROM locations l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN projects p on l.l_id = p.l_id 
GROUP BY l.parent_id
```

Comment: @7even: you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63732322/edit) to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two joins:

```
select d.l_id, d.title, count(p.l_id) count_p_id
from locations d
left join locations l on l.parent_id = d.l_id
left join projects  p on p.l_id      = l.l_id
where d.parent_id = 0
group by d.l_id, d.title
```

The query starts from the list of districts (`d`), whose parent is `0`. Then, it goes down one level to the locations (`l`), and looks up the corresponding projects (`p`). The final step is aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of GMB returns this 1 row

```
l_id    title       count_p_id
1       Country     0
```

using this script version

```
select d.l_id, d.title, count(p.l_id) count_p_id
from locations d
left join locations l on l.parent_id = d.l_id
left join projects  p on p.l_id      = l.l_id
where d.parent_id = 0
group by d.l_id, d.title
```

We get the desired result with the slightly corrected condition

```
where d.parent_id = 1
```

Result:

```
l_id    title       count_p_id
2       District1   2
3       District2   2
4       District3   2
5       District4   0
```

*Sorry for posting the answer, instead of a simple comment, which would be sufficient, but don't have enough reputation credits yet.*